# In powershell, using the export-csv cmdlet, my ints are being encapsulated by quotes any idea why?

Tags: powershell

So I run a sql query that I pipe to export-csv, the only problem is that all the values are encapsulated by quotes, including ints, this is impossible for me to reimport into SQL as ints, any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSV has no notion of types. It's a purely string-based format. PowerShell just quotes every value since it's easier and the space gain by not quoting where not required is often negligible.

It also includes, as a comment, in the first line the original type of the objects exported. PowerShell then uses this to reconstruct it when loading the file. But still, every property is a string, then, because, as noted, CSV has no type information.

What you can do afterwards is to reconstruct the types:

```
Import-CSV foo | %{
  $_.SomeIntProperty = [int]$_.SomeIntProperty
  ...
  $_
}
```

Or don't export as CSV but as CLIXML.

Comment: Don't have the ability to upvote, but if I did, you'd get one! Thanks

Comment: So I still haven't come up with a suitable way to get done what I need to get done, basically, I need to upload a CSV I created that has ints and varchars mostly, any idea how to do it? If there was an option to not place quotations, that would be amazing.

Comment: You can post-process the CSV by removing quotes around numbers with something like `(gc foo.csv) -replace '(?<!")"(\d+)"(?!")', '$1'|Out-File -Enc UTF8 foo.csv` (might work, untested, but you get the idea, I guess).

Answer (score 0):

they are being exported as strings not as integers.