# PowerShell Export-Csv will not export integer without quotes

Tags: c#, powershell, csv

I have a PSObject like so:

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "int"=0;
    "str"="string";
}
```

However, when I run `$obj | Export-Csv -Path "test.csv"` I get:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"str","int"
"string","0"
```

What gives? Shouldn't the output be:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"str","int"
"string",0
```

My program recieving this file won't validate the CSV if an integer has quotes. Don't ask me why...

EDIT: [I found a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710283/in-powershell-using-the-export-csv-cmdlet-my-ints-are-being-encapsulated-by-qu) that asks this as well. Is the answer really to do post-processing regex to fix the file?! Seems like there needs to be a switch on `Export-Csv` to allow this.

Comment: what makes you think it shouldn't be encased in double quotes?

Comment: You would first need to assign a 'type' to the fields in the object. You could pipeline it through something that removes quotes from numbers, but who's to say that number isn't just an number in a string field? I don't know whats with all the downvotes here.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid They are already typed. In testing that changes nothing for me. Strongly typed or no

Comment: @OwainEsau I agree that traditionally CSV files have no type. But the program I have to import this data to apparently has a different idea and gives errors if the numbers I am importing are encased in quotes.I was just annoyed I had to write a workaround to make this work.

Comment: fair enough if the program your importing too requires it, see my answer, should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as per your example:

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "int"=0;
    "str"="string";
}

$obj  | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\owain.esau\Desktop\Test\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | % {$obj.int -replace '"',''}
```